# What does the little number in IIS Express system tray manager mean?

Tags: iis-express

When opening the system tray adminstration tool for IIS Express there is a little number at the side of the site name (here the number 3):

[image]

Can anyone tell me, what that means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number does not mean anything, it is part of the site name. Here "...Web(3)" is site name. If you want you can rename it.

1. Open %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config
2. Search for 'Site(3)' and rename it